# Mobile App build in SAP WEB IDE is pulling in the wrong App Id from Mobile Services

Tags: android, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, sap-mobile-services

When Deploying a Mobile app from Web IDE to Mobile services, the app Details in appconfig.js config.xml are being pulled from the incorrect mobile services sub-account.

This can be corrected by deleting the app in mobile services and building again.

E.g.

Mobile app built in DEV sub-account (fine).

WEB IDE Codebase pushed to Git repo (bitbucket) - Pulled into TEST sub-account WEB-IDE.

App is built in TEST WEB IDE which deploys to TEST mobile services (fine).

The above works as there was no previous instance of the App in mobile services in both DEV and TEST enviroments.

However, When making changes to the App in WEB IDE, our troubles started.

We made a change to the project in DEV, built it again, no problem.

However, pushed these changes and pulled into TEST WEB IDE, and built the mobile app again in TEST, the app details (appconfig.js, config.xml) were pulled in from DEV as opposed to TEST.

... We corrected this in TEST by deleted the app in mobile services and building again. Pushing the changes to bitbucket.

However, pulling the project back into DEV gives the same issue in that it's now pulling the app details from TEST!

Could you please help with the following...

a) Is deleting the app in mobile services the only solution. If it is this isn't workable as it involves removing and reconfiguring the app in mobile services for each update. The app has offline config which needs to be set up every time.

b) What is your recommended method for deploying changed through a landscape of DEV, TEST, (and eventually PROD). Are we approaching this the right way?

It would be great if we could resolve the problem of WEB IDE / mobile services apparently losing their connection as above.

We don't manually update the configuration files when building the Mobile App.

I thought also that the issue may be the project.json file which is being pushed to git. But I changed this to the correct app ID and it still pulls across from the wrong sub-account.

Comment: All in all, this all sounds like nonsense. On the first hand, WebIDE is used per-subaccont, so you cannot fetch another subaccount file into the same project.Secondly, why don't you create 3 Git repos one for each subaccount and move files across them when needed? Don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding project.json, config.xml and appconfig.json to gitignore.

This way, any sub-account setting aren't overwritten when pulling the project from Git.